Identify this Italian comedy
I'm looking for the name of an Italian comedy film that takes place on a cruise ship.  I saw the movie on TV in Florence, Italy in 2006.
The premise of the comedy is a family (mother/father/children) taking a cruise and the husband is cheating on his wife with a younger woman.  The girlfriend shows up on the same cruise ship and he finds out.  There is a costume party night planned on the ship and he decides to disguise himself as a mummy to avoid her.  It was hysterical!

That's the average plot of any "Cinepanettone" with Christian  De Sica.

Are you totally sure about the year? There is a movie called "Natale in crociera", but it was released in 2007: IMDB http://www.imdb.com/Name?tt1065329


"That's the average plot of any "Cinepanettone" with Christian De Sica"

Couldn't be truer ... :)
The movie you are looking for is Natale sul Nilo (2002) directed by Neri Parenti and starring (of course) Christian De Sica.
Here is a short synopsis from Wikipedia

The Roman lawyer Fabio Ciulla goes on holiday to Egypt. He is pursuing his wife, whom he has repeatedly betrayed, in an attempt to persuade her to forgive him. The police sergeant Enrico Ombroni also travels to the land of the Pharaohs with a guard (Biagio Izzo) to get his young daughter away from a musical group of which she is a fan. The two protagonists meet in Egypt for an exchange of misunderstandings, since Ciulla by mistake has a love affair with a young girl while his wife forgives him.

A frame of the scene you were talking about

and here at this link (circa 12 minutes into the clip) you can watch the whole De Sica's episode.

YES!!!!!! TY....THAT'S THE MOVIE

Glad I've been of help. I'm not a fan of the whole "Natale ..." franchise nor of Christian De Sica, his father Vittorio instead is a whole other matter. Anyway, if you're interested in the genre they made plenty of them from the '80s on. Here's a list of some of them Cinepanettoni, although I'm not sure how many of them have been dubbed in English (maybe the recent ones). Don't forget to accept the answer ;)

Again, thank your for all the info!!
